# Reading Excel content from POST request by PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I use PHPExcel to read excel content from HTTP POST request instead of writing temporary file to hard disk then read it?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507898/reading-spreadsheet-using-phpexcel?

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you very much.